# Does Trezor have any shortfalls security-wise?

Tags: wallet, private-key, coldstorage, trezor

Or do you have a recommendation for another cold wallet?

Comment: First, thanks for getting involved and asking so many questions!  It really helps make this SE site a more useful resource.  Second, is there any way you can expand the context of this question, making it a bit more clear what you want to know?  It was auto-flagged as "low-quality" because of how short it is, so it is in danger of being closed by the community.  Asking for specific security concerns about the Trezor will likely attract more answers, as well as being more useful to those seeking the same answers.